# How to wrap iframe size inside a bootstrap modal

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

Actually i'm trying to show a iframe inside a bootstrap modal but the issue is that iframe content is dynamic so the size can change every time someone will open that model.

Like here the modal is too big so there is a lot of white space

[image]

But when the iframe has a lot of items it's looking "fine"

[image]

Here is the modal code

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">

        <!--Content-->
        <div class="modal-content">

            <!--Body-->
            <div class="modal-body mb-0 p-0">

                <div class="embed-responsive z-depth-1-half" style="height:100%">
                    <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="frameticket.aspx"></iframe>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
        <!--/.Content-->

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @MohitGupta any suggestion?

Comment: Could you  make a code snippet or codepen of your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewrite height of modal-content like that

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">

        <!--Content-->
        <div class="modal-content" style="height:auto; max-height:400px; overflow-y: scroll">

            <!--Body-->
            <div class="modal-body mb-0 p-0">

                <div class="embed-responsive z-depth-1-half" style="height:100%">
                    <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="frameticket.aspx"></iframe>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
        <!--/.Content-->

    </div>
</div>
```